# Avoid access to www files outside Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, permissions

I need some links to local HTML files inside my Shiny app. These files are in /www dir and Shiny can access them correctly but anybody can see them via URL_SHINY_APP/**filename.html** too. That's wrong because the Shiny app has login with user and password. How I can set the permissions for achieve this?
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What is the authentication scheme being used?